# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Error parsing near '<HTML dir=“ltr”>

Tags: 2007, page-layout

I have an aspx page in SharePoint's _layout folder. This page loads user controls from the controltemplates folder. User controls has ajax update panels.

I am getting below error when I'm working with page.

```
Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received
from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response
is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server
 trace
     is enabled.
        Details: Error parsing near '<HTML dir="ltr">
        <H'.
        Line: 4723
        Char: 21
        Code: 0
        URI: http://mysitename.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=5kqA7Nw-EeaK3p4QkMYAWi......
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: If you have access to the page, try to disable/comment out the update panel. This -should- provide you with a more readable error (or at least a correlation id that you may use to search for further info in the uls logs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got fixed this. I was getting some permission issue while updating list. I got fixed this and no more errors.

Thanks